# How to unrender/detach/remove ZingChart library from specific div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zingchart

I used below code to **render zingchart** which works fine.

```
zingchart.render({ 
    id : 'myChart', 
    data : myConfig, 
    height: 400, 
    width: "100%"
});
```

Now in some occasion I want to **un render** or **detach** it. I Mean when I click on some specific place this div with id `myChart` should be empty and **zing chart should be removed** from it.

**How can i achieve it?**

**I tried** this jquery code as well.

```
$("#myChart").html('');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Full disclosure, I'm a member of the ZingChart team.

Deleting the DOM element the chart is attached to will not delete the chart from memory. At this point you will have something along the lines of a dangling reference. You achieve proper destruction using our api method [destroy](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/developers/api-methods/#zingchart__exec__api__destroy)

```
zingchart.exec('myChart','destroy');
```

Comment: Kindly have a look on following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786277/can-i-render-multiple-charts-by-single-renderfunction-call-in-zing-charts

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, I added star on github aswell

Comment: Hi [nardecky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5712661/nardecky), Is there any why I could destroy all zingchart on a single page at once?

Comment: I believe the best way would be to save id's of charts. So you have an array of id's OR you could add a class to the container div, a naming pattern. Then you could do something like `document.querySelectorAll('.chart-class')` and loop through each HTML element grabbing the `id` property.