# Can I render multiple charts by single renderfunction call in ZingChart?

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

I visited **ZingChart's** documentation and came to know the methods of **rendering multiple charts** by **calling multiple render functions** like this.

```
  zingchart.render({
    id:'chartDiv1',
    data:myChart1,
    height:300,
    width:500
  });
  zingchart.render({
    id:'chartDiv2',
    data:myChart2,
    height:300,
    width:500       
  });
  zingchart.render({
    id:'chartDiv3',
    data:myChart3,
    height:300,
    width:500
  });
  zingchart.render({
    id:'dashboardDiv',
    data:myDashboard,
    height:500,
    width:700
  });
```

But in my code I want to **write less code** which should work more for me as its also **directed by my boss**.

So my question is **Can I render multiple charts by just calling one render function**?
some thing like:

```
zingchart.render({
    id:{'chartDiv1','chartDiv2','chartDiv3','chartDiv4'},
    data:{myChart1,myChart2,myChart3,myChart4},
    height:300,
    width:500
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full disclosure, I'm a member of the ZingChart team.

We currently do not support the example code above but there are a couple ways you could do this with javascript.

```
function renderZingCharts(_id,_data) {
  zingchart.render({
    id: _id,
    data: _data,
    height:300,
    width:500
  });
}

renderZingCharts('chartDiv1', myChart1);
renderZingCharts('chartDiv2', myChart2);
renderZingCharts('chartDiv3', myChart3);
renderZingCharts('chartDiv4', myChart4);
```

You Could also loop through if you want to keep the array content.

```
function renderZingCharts(aIds, aData) {

  // do some sanity checks for length of two arrays here ???

  for (var i=0; i < aIds.length; i++) {
    zingchart.render({
      id: aIds[i],
      data: aData[i],
      height:300,
      width:500
    });
  }
}
var ids = ['chartDiv1', 'chartDiv2', 'chartDiv3', 'chartDiv4'];
var configs = [myChart1, myChart2, myChart3, myChart4];
renderZingCharts(ids,configs);
```

Comment: I got your point, but i will suggest to keep this scenario in mind for your future updates, Thanks.